# Choosing the Most Recently Entered Non-Blank Value When Many Values Exist

Tags: oracle, timestamp

I have run into a problem where some IDs have multiple names associated with them.  That is, if I have a location ID from one table and need to pull the location's name from another table based on the location ID, the query is returning multiple names.  I want to choose the newest name based on a timestamp, if that one is not blank (that is, it's *not* null, but many of the entries are just a blank space).

TABLE LOCATIONS:

```
LOCATION_ID   LOCATION_NAME    LOCATION_TS
  12345         'BEST AUTO'        4
  12345         'BESTAUTO'         3
  12345         ' '                5
  12347         'FETTS'            3
  12347         'FESTS'            2
```

TABLE LOCATION_DETAIL:

```
LOCATION_ID    LOCATION_TYPE
  12345         'AA'
  12347         'ZQ'
```

I am trying to get a result that looks like this:

```
LOCATION_ID   LOCATION_NAME    LOCATION_TYPE
  12345         'BEST AUTO'        'AA'
  12347         'FETTS'            'ZQ'
```

[Here is an SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/64332/4).  I am using Oracle 11g.  I have been spinning my wheels on this for a while and I feel like I'm missing something obvious.  I should mention that the way my permissions are set up, pretty much the only thing I can do is query the database, not create views or tables, update data, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is generally known as a "greatest of group" solution.  There are several patterns for this.  A search of dba.SE or SO will show you some.

The posted question and the SQL Fiddle have the table names swapped.  This code is from the Fiddle:

```
with NEWEST as
(
    select
        LOCATION_ID,
        MAX(LOCATION_TS) as MAX_TS
    from Location_detail
    where Location_name is not null
    and LOCATION_NAME <> ' '         -- or whatever your exclusion conditions are
    group by LOCATION_ID
)
select
    l.LOCATION_ID,
    ld.LOCATION_NAME,
    l.LOCATION_TYPE
from LOCATIONS l
LEFT OUTER JOIN NEWEST n
ON l.LOCATION_ID = n.LOCATION_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN LOCATION_DETAIL ld
on ld.LOCATION_ID = n.LOCATION_ID
and ld.LOCATION_TS = n.MAX_TS;
```